# Connection refused when attempting to connect to a docker container on an EC2

Tags: docker, amazon-ec2, docker-compose, port, docker-network

I'm currently running a spring boot application in a docker container on an EC2. My docker-compose file looks like this (with some values replaced):

```
version: '3.8'

services:

  my-app:
    image: ${ecr-repo}/my-app:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT
    ports:
    - "8893:8839/tcp"

networks:
  default:
```

The docker container deploys  and comes up as healthy with the healthcheck command being:

```
wget --spider -q -Y off http://localhost:8893/my-app/v1/actuator/health
```

If I do a docker ps -a I can see for the ports:

```
0.0.0.0:8893->8893
```

My Alb healthcheck however is returning a 502 so I've temporarily allowed connections from my IP directly to the EC2 in the security group. The rules are:

```
Allow Ingress on 8893 from my Alb security group
Allow Ingress on 8893 from my IP
Allow Egress to anywhere (0.0.0.0)
```

When I try and hit the healthcheck endpoint of my app using the public DNS of the ec2 on port 8893 using Postman I get Error: connect ECONNREFUSED

If I take my docker container down and then simulate a webserver using the command from https://fabianlee.org/2016/09/26/ubuntu-simulating-a-web-server-using-netcat/ which is:

```
while true; do { echo -e "HTTP/1.1 200 OK\r\n$(date)\r\n\r\n<h1>hello world from $(hostname) on $(date)</h1>" |  nc -vl 8080; } done
```

I get a 200 response with the expected body which indicates it's not a problem with the security groups.

The actuator endpoint for spring boot is definitely enabled as if I try running the app through intellij and hitting the endpoint it returns a 200 and status up.

Any suggestions for what I might be missing here or how I could debug this further? It seems like docker isn't picking up connections to the port for some reason.

Comment: Does the container run in a local development environment (where AWS security groups aren't a concern)?  Can you connect to the container from an ssh session on the EC2 instance?

Comment: Looks like it doesn't but I get "Error: socket hang up" instead of connection refused

Comment: Locally that is. Will try on the EC2 later